# how to use refere() function to redirection in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

I wanted to redirect on same page from where it redirect to login. Cake php has function referer() to use this. Mostly people suggest to use it with AUTH Component.But i am not using auth. So please Help me how to use referer() without auth component.

Comment: This is very confusing. Are you asking to redirect to login? Something like `$this->redirect('/users/login');`? Or do you actually want to redirect to the referer?

Answer (score 2):

did you try to look into the documenation?
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::redirect

there it states the exact same thing:

```
If you need to redirect to the referer page you can use:
$this->redirect($this->referer());
```

Referer() has nothing do to with Auth.

Answer (score 0):

from CakePHP document. AuthComponent will handle redirect to the page that you request for you by $this->Auth->redirect().

```
// UsersController.php

public function login() {
  if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    if ($this->Auth->login()) {
      return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
    } else {
      $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or password is incorrect'), 'default', array(), 'auth');
    }
  }
}
```